# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext and Impersonation in a WCF service

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

Working with the `PrincipalContext` in code that lies behind a WCF service.  The WCF service is impersonating, to allow a 'pass-through' type authentication.

While everything else I do with Active Directory (mostly the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace) works fine in this scenario, for some reason the classes in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement throw a fit.  Sample code that fails:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
UserPrincipal user = 
    UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, UserName);
```

When I make the call to `FindByIdentity`, I get a COMException:  "An operations error has occurred".  Calls to the `PrincipalContext` also fail, e.g.:

```
string server = context.ConnectedServer;
```

Both `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext` and `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` show the impersonation is working correctly.  And, like I say, other AD tasks in S.DS.P work fine.

If I explicitly set credentials on the `PrincipalContext`, everything works.  For example:

```
PrincipalContext context = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, user, password);
UserPrincipal user = 
    UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, UserName);
```

Now everything works.  But I won't know the username and password from the caller; I must rely on the impersonation.

Any ideas on what would cause the issue I'm seeing?

Thanks in advance!
James

Answer (score 1):

Make sure an spn is set  for the app pool, delegation is set in AD, and that the app pool account has the act as part of the os privilege.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an spn for the app pool; I'm using an app pool dedicated to this service, just not sure what an spn is.  What do you have to set in AD for delegation?  I'll check on the last one

Comment: spn = Service Principal Name